# How to use Java 18 on Pi

Tags: java, minecraft

Following https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-4-as-a-minecraft-java-server to make a Minecraft server. The only thing I changed is the server jar itself, BUT Minecraft 1.18.2 requires Java 18. Installed it from snap when I tried to run it said bash: java command not found

TL;DR: Trying to run Java 18 from snap in terminal
(Sorry for the bad English. It's not my main language)

Comment: What's the question? What part doesn't work? How does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on this website: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-18-on-ubuntu-debian/. Try following part 1 first, and if that fails, try following part 2.

Answer (score 0):

To run 1.18.x - 1.19.x Minecraft server you need JDK 17, JDK 18 will likely be unstable.

On PI you can install TemurinJDK (ex Adoptopenjdk) distribution by following [their instructions](https://adoptium.net/installation/linux/).
Do note that you will likely need to put `sudo` before `tee`.

I'm currently able to install TemurinJDK 8, 11, 17 and 18.

If you can't find the version you are looking for, you can look into older Adoptopenjdk distributions (8, 11-16)